# Reason to set queue size of ROS publisher or subscriver to a large value

Tags: message-queue, ros, publisher, subscriber

When I look over the tutorial of Robot Operating system (ROS), I found most [example codes](http://wiki.ros.org/ja/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) set the publisher's queue size to a larger value such as 1000. I think this leads to losing real-time response of the node.

For what purpose, do people set it to that large value?

Comment: I also interested in this. Usually, I just set it to be 10 or 100 without thinking. Any1 can explain?

Comment: But, if you set it to less, you risk losing some of the data. Sometimes, it is important to record all the data and then you can have some lag in the computation, but you won't lose any intermediate data. That could be a possible reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From ROS docs (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber):

Message publisher (producer):
"The second parameter to advertise() is the size of the message queue
used for publishing messages.  If messages are published more quickly
than we can send them, the number here specifies how many messages to
buffer up before throwing some away."

Message subscriber:
"The second parameter to the subscribe() function is the size of the message queue.  If messages are arriving faster than they are being processed, this is the number of messages that will be buffered up before beginning to throw away the oldest ones."

Possible explanation:
Think in the consumer-producer problem.

You can't guarantee that you will consume messages in the rate they arrive. So you create a queue that is filled as messages comes by sender (some sensor for instance). 
Bad case: If your program delays in some other part and you can't read the messages in the rate they arrived the queue increases. 
Good case: As soon as your other processing load diminishes you can read the queue faster and start to reduce it. If you have available time you will end up reducing queue size to zero.

So as for your question, if you send queue size to large value you may guarantee that will not lose messages. In a simple example you have no memory constraints so you can do anything you want, like use many GBytes of RAM to create a large queue and assures will always work. **Or if you create a toy example to explain a concept you don't want your program to crash for other reasons**.

A real life example can be a scenario of a waiter and a kitchen to wash dishes.
Suppose the costumers ends its meals and the waiter takes their dirty dishes to wash in the kitchen. He puts in a table. Whenever the dishwasher can, he goes to table and gets dishes and take to wash. In normal operation the table is never filled. But if someone else give another task to the dishwasher guy, the table will start to get full. Until some time the waiter can't place dishes anymore and leave tables dirty (problem in the system). But if table is artificially large there (let's say 1000 square units) the waiter will likely fulfill its job even if dishwasher is busy, considering that after some time he will be able to return to clean dishes.

Ok, long answer, but it may be of help to understand queues.